# Accessing other script method from instantiated object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to set my game up to where there is a player, you touch the screen to throw the object, once that object collides with another object 1 point is added to the score. I added a script to the instantiated object that prints a message, to the console, when a collision is detected. The script also has a reference to another script holding the score variable.

The script is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CrackEgg : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stats stats;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "BreakEgg")
        {
            stats.DepositMoney();
            Debug.Log("I am actually working");
        }
    }

}
```

The Stats script is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Bank")]
    public int bankAmount;
    public int depositAmount;

    public void DepositMoney()
    {
        bankAmount += depositAmount;
    }
}
```

I know I have to have the Stats script attached to a game object(I have it attached to an empty game object). The thrown object is a prefab and has the `CrackEgg` script as a component. I try to drag the Stats game object into the Stats field of the `CrackEgg` script but it doesn't work. It only works if the Stats game object is also a prefab. The main issue I'm having is that even when I have the Stats game object prefab in the hierarchy, when I test the code, the `bankAmount` variable does not increase at all. As a summary, I want the instantiated object to detect a collision then run the `DepositMoney()` method, from the Stats script, but am not able to find a way to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Quick check: create a `CrackEgg` on the scene. Try to drag the `Stats` object into the field. It should work. Now drag this `CrackEgg` to the Project View in order to create a prefab. The `Stats` field is empty on the prefab. Why?

A prefab can be instantiated anywhere in your game, so it's possible this reference to a scene object is not valid in case the prefab is instantiated in another scene.
So you must get the reference to the `Stats` object in runtime.

You can accomplish that in two ways:

**METHOD 1**

Tag your `Stats` object with a "Stats" tag.

[image: Add Tag to Game Object in Unity]

Then locate it in the scene whenever you start a `CrackEgg`.

```
class CrackEgg : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        stats = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Stats").GetComponent<Stats>();
    }
}
```

**METHOD 2**

Make your `Stats` class static, and not a MonoBehaviour component.

```
public class Stats
{
    private static int bankAmount;

    public static void DepositMoney(int depositAmount)
    {
        bankAmount += depositAmount;
    }
}
```

Then you don't add it to any object, since there's always a single instance of each parameter on the program. This is an usual pattern for score classes.
To access it, you don't need to store a reference to `Stats`, just use the class name:

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "BreakEgg")
{
    Stats.DepositMoney(depositAmount);
    Debug.Log("I am actually working");
}
```

Since you can't assign values to static classes on the Editor, I've suggested a modification where the caller defines the deposit amount when calling. You might need to think about the safety issues (don't allow values out of a range, etc).

Also, it's usually recommended you use `CompareTag` instead of `==`: https://answers.unity.com/questions/200820/is-comparetag-better-than-gameobjecttag-performanc.html

Comment: This assumes however that there is only exactly ONE `Stats` instance in the entire scene